# How to get out of > mode in linux terminal

Tags: bash

I am using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 on a remote server.

After source `~/.bashrc` command, I got into some sort of mode I am not very aware of. Instead of `bash $` or `bash #` now what I have is `bash:~ >` and by changing directory it keep on changing with `bash:/somedirectory >`

Can someone please explain what is going on and how to get back into the normal mode.

```
# Generic $dotdir/bashshrc
# Engineering Services (ES)
#
##
# Things the user might wish to set.
export USER_PATH="~/bin"            # Extra paths.
export EDITOR=vi                # Preferred editor.
export PRINTER=lp               # Preferred printer.
export NNTPSERVER=usenet.cisco.com      # Preferred news server.
 

##
# Should the full environment be set up even for non-interactive shells?
# Probably not but here is a variable to control it.
export FULLENV=false                # 'true' or 'false'

##
# Should all paths (even NFS, which might hang) be set up at login?
# The alias "fullpath" is available to setup your full path.  It can
# also be used to change your path by changing USER_PATH above.
export FULLPATH=true                # 'true' or 'false'

###########################################################################
# Everything above this line helps configure the environment.

# This line should not be removed.
dotdir=~/.files; [ -f $dotdir/sys_bashrc ] && . $dotdir/sys_bashrc
[ $FULLENV != "true" ] && [ -z "$PS1" ] && return

###########################################################################
# Everything below this line is run for interactive shells.
# If you wish the full environment even in non-interactive
# shells set FULLENV above to 'true'.

umask 022                        # no write by group or other
export autologout=0              # disable autologout
export FIGNORE=".o"              # don't complete .o files
# export HISTFILE=~/.bash_history  # history file - this setting is now externally enforced by Secops, please don't modify.
# export HISTFILESIZE=500        # history file size - this setting is now externally enforced by Secops, please don't modify.
# export HISTSIZE=128            # save last 128 commands - this setting is now externally enforced by Secops, please don't modify.
export ignoreeof=10              # disable ^D for logout (up to 10)
set -C                           # disable redirect overwrite
set -b                           # enable immediate job notify
export PS1="\h:\w > "            # shell prompt format

##
# Source other rc files after this line.
[ -f ~/.bashrc_LOB ] && . ~/.bashrc_LOB
[ -f ~/.bashrc_BU ] && . ~/.bashrc_BU
[ -f ~/.bashrc_USER ] && . ~/.bashrc_USER
```

I opened the file to edit path. But didn't make any change except a extra space to check write permissions.

Comment: Take a look what `.bashrc` does? No way for us to tell without knowing its contents.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/671904/edit) your question and add the contents of `.bashrc`. Please enclose the text in the curly brackets `{}` to maintain readability. [From Review](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions/390453)

Comment: Welcome, why did you source `.bashrc`? Did you do any changes to it?

Comment: '>' is usually the value of PS2, the secondary prompt. It means you are in the middle of an incomplete bash statement. So check your bashrc for any unbalanced syntax -- quotes, brackets etc. Especially check any recent changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `>`  is the default *secondary prompt* (determined by `$PS2` variable) for Bash, your case looks more like you may have accidentally changed the primary prompt (`$PS1`).

As mentioned by Paul_Pedant in the comments, the secondary prompt appears when you are trying to execute a command that has unbalanced quotes or brackets, or an unterminated statement (`if ... then ... fi`, `case ... esac`, `do ... done`).

But since you can change directories, it is more likely that the primary prompt has now been changed by `~/.bashrc` to look similar to the secondary prompt: if you were really at the secondary prompt, any commands you typed would be used to extend whatever unfinished quote/bracket/statement block triggered it in the first place, and the command would actually be executed only after you completed the unfinished block. That would mean you would not be able to change directories if you were in a real secondary prompt.

The simplest fix for that would be to just change the primary prompt back to a value that is more familiar to you. For example:

```
export PS1='bash \$ '
```

The `\$` has a special significance in the primary prompt: it expands to `#` if you are root, and to `$` if you are a regular user.

---

The change was caused by this line in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PS1="\h:\w > "            # shell prompt format
```

You could comment it out, or if you find the display of `hostname:current directory` in the prompt useful, you could change that line to:

```
export PS1="\h:\w \$ "            # shell prompt format
```

to have the `$` / `#` character in the prompt behave as you've used to, while keeping the hostname and current working directory displayed in the prompt.

Comment: it's working. but after exiting and logging in again. I am having same issue of >

Comment: @AshutoshRana  Sounds like you did not find all cases of changing PS1, or you made the export in the current shell but did not edit the file to make it permanent. I have even seen cases of a login rc file resetting another file from a backup before sourcing it.